# For a chat system with 40,000 users, which would be more scalable: polling or websocket?

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, websocket, chat

there is our web site using jomsocial chat component and we want to have mobile/android chat application

so
there is some ways to do it but some guys told me to do it with polling and some guys told to do it with web socket and using NodeJS

the social website contains betwean 30.000 and 40.000 members, If We Use Polling Server Will Take Down
whitch one of our solutions works and server never get down if users us our chat service?

First Solution Is Using Polling But Server Will Care OverFlow , Second Is WebSocket To Stop OverFlowing
A Way To WebSocket Is [Node JS](http://nodejs.org)

Comment: Can you phrase a specific question with enough detail about your situation such that it could be answered in a factual way that was not just people's opinions?  In general, webSockets were invented because they are more efficient than polling (if supported on a given browser).

Comment: It appears that English is not a strength, but you need to ask a more specific question.  If you're trying to ask: "For a chat system with 40,000 users, which would be more scalable: polling or websocket"?, then please add that question to your post.  If not, add some other question.  There should be an actual question in your post.